# How to deal with "None" DB values in Django queries

Tags: python, django

I have the following filter query which is doing an SQL OR statement:

```
results = Stores.objects.filter(Q(title__icontains=prefs.address1) | Q(title__icontains=prefs.address2))
```

This works fine but if the prefs.address1 and prefs.address2 values (which come from another model) are blank in mySQL, Django complains with the following error:

> Cannot use None as a query value

Is there an elegant way to check to see if my filter values are not blank before constructing the OR filter query?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do this which is easily generalisable to more queries

```
query = Q()
for search in (prefs.address1, prefs.address2):
    if search:
        query |= Q(title__icontains=search)
results = Stores.objects.filter(query)
```

Answer (score 3):

This?

```
thefilter = Q(title__icontains=prefs.address1)
if prefs.address2 is not None:
    thefilter = thefilter | Q(title__icontains=prefs.address2)
results = Stores.objects.filter( thefilter)
```